# How do I remove the /movies showing all files/folders within the directory?

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd

[image]

I was wondering how would I remove this so people can’t do it with out a password? or just even no one would be able to do it, I’m hosing the website on Apache on my raspberry pi 4 2gb

Also how can I password protect certain webpages?

Comment: how do you hose a website?

Comment: What does this picture mean? What directories you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You want to follow a guide like here and put your access file in place.

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216363187-Password-protecting-your-site-with-an-htaccess-file

Answer (score 0):

Or you can look at the official documentation

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html